# Getting this error message before am able to install ubuntu desktop 16.04.1

Tags: system-installation

Been trying to install Ubuntu desktop on our forensics computer so that it could run alongside Windows 10, but keep on getting stuck on this error message.

```
[    2.074246] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: ERROR Transfer event for disabled endpoint
 or incorrect stream ring
[    2.074303] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: @00000008694f7580 00000000 00000000 1b0000
00 01038001
[    2.079871] xhcd_hcd 0000:04:00.0: ERROR Transfer event for disabled endpoint
 or incorrect stream ring
[    2.079924] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: @00000008694f7a40 00000000 00000000 1b0000
00 02038001
[    3.080201] sd 12:0:0:0: [sde] Asking for cache data failed
[    3.080244] sd 12:0:0:0: [sde] Assuming drive cache: write through
[    8.734985] usb 3-5: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[   13.951227] usb 3-5: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[   19.279631] usb 3-5: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[   24.495884] usb 3-5: device descriptor read/64, error -71
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I should mention that I am trying to install from USB

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a [possible kernel bug](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=90651) related to external USB 3.0 hard disks.  If you do have a USB-connected hard disk, you might try removing it while you install Ubuntu.

If that lets you install Ubuntu, but you get the same problem when you plug the USB hard disk back in, then you might try the workaround in [this forum thread](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=183190) (see #12).  Good luck.

Comment: Any idea on how to go about solving the problem? Not really finding anything on the linked source

Comment: Hi @GeorgeApodaca, I edited my answer to give more information.  Good luck!

Comment: thank you @rclocher3. One more clarification, if I may. I've downloaded the ISO image onto a USB stick and am trying to install it to a second hard drive on our forensics computer. The first drive currently has Windows 10 and Win98 DOS. It's this second drive I'm trying to install ubuntu/bitcurator onto.

Comment: Do you have a USB-connected external hard disk, and if so, is that where you're trying to install Ubuntu?

Comment: It's a digital forensics computer (FRED) so it has two HD slots embedded into the tower that connect directly to the computer. So it is not a USB-connected external hard disk (tho perhaps that may be an easier option to consider). The actual Ubuntu/BitCurator ISO image has been loaded onto the USB and connected to the computer so that it will hopefully boot and install onto the second HD that is connected to the tower. Does that make sense?

Comment: I see that you said you're using a USB stick.  Were you able to "Try Ubuntu" when booting from the USB stick, or do you get that error right away when you try to boot, or is it just when you try to install Ubuntu?

Comment: Once the computer turns on, I press F8 which allows me to choose the USB stick as a boot option. When I select Ubuntu from the boot menu, it gives me an Ubuntu load screen but then shortly thereafter gives me the error message I included in the pic. It then continues on to a different Ubuntu loading page, seemingly trying to load the image, but fails and restarts after 5-8 minutes. (Sorry for the late reply!)